# WebRTC iceconnectionstatechange: disconnected

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to make a simple video chat using webRTC. When connected to a local network, everything is fine, but when you try to connect via the Internet, at the very end, the connection is terminated.

I am using `iceServers: [{urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]` but it doesn't seem to help.

`chrome://webrtc-internals/` shows that every candidate was successfully transferred, stops for about 15 seconds and prints:

```
iceconnectionstatechange disconnected 
iceconnectionstatechange(legacy) failed
```

All those 15 seconds `peer.connectionState` is `connecting` and then changes `failed` on both sides.

Sorry, i can't put here code because it's a lot, but you can test it here https://nekita.glitch.me. I'm putting out a lot of information in console for debugging purposes, plus you can visit `chrome://webrtc-internals/` for even more.

Edit 1:
I found https://appr.tc and tried to connect through this site. I got same error message, so i assume I wrote everything correctly and it's just some firewall or NAT blocking my connection?..

Edit 2: After some time stun server error 701 popped out:[image: chrome web internals]

Edit3: Found detailed webrtc log in Firefox:

```
Local SDP (offer)
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-81.0.2 2239752409517003904 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 02:B5:AB:B8:30:2A:E1:FF:B4:A0:FB:9B:FB:7C:18:58:92:04:9C:DC:F2:CE:AD:26:A9:FA:B7:A5:ED:8D:E0:FF
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 24425 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 213.222.245.173
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 1035 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 TCP 2105524479 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 1036 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 TCP 2105524478 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 213.222.245.173 3364 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 213.222.245.173 24425 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0
a=recvonly
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ice-pwd:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309
a=ice-ufrag:44add4f4
a=mid:0
a=rtcp:3364 IN IP4 213.222.245.173
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:3167650112 cname:{d81549a7-fd27-48eb-98ed-5c81302e4412}
m=video 24788 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98
c=IN IP4 213.222.245.173
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 1037 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 TCP 2105524479 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 1038 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 TCP 2105524478 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 213.222.245.173 24788 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 213.222.245.173 3688 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0
a=recvonly
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:124 apt=120
a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
a=fmtp:125 apt=121
a=fmtp:127 apt=126
a=fmtp:98 apt=97
a=ice-pwd:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309
a=ice-ufrag:44add4f4
a=mid:1
a=rtcp:3688 IN IP4 213.222.245.173
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:870906877 cname:{d81549a7-fd27-48eb-98ed-5c81302e4412}
m=application 56342 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 213.222.245.173
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 1034 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 TCP 2105524479 7042dae1-a7df-4a62-af6b-532b75b4c9dc.local 9 typ host tcptype active
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 213.222.245.173 56342 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-pwd:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309
a=ice-ufrag:44add4f4
a=mid:2
a=setup:actpass
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:1073741823

Remote SDP (Answer)
v=0
o=- 9067351238289188318 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2
a=msid-semantic:WMS pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:668138274 1 udp 2122262783 2a00:1fa1:2ef:9e60:71c8:4b3f:1b27:2e38 40013 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 2 network-cost 900
a=candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900
a=candidate:1766918098 1 tcp 1518283007 2a00:1fa1:2ef:9e60:71c8:4b3f:1b27:2e38 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 2 network-cost 900
a=candidate:2639871532 1 tcp 1518214911 10.132.138.120 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900
a=candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900
a=sendonly
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fingerprint:sha-256 BA:56:72:51:3B:38:D9:16:D6:3C:F6:22:E3:DB:33:FF:AA:57:57:D1:D2:0D:AA:0F:91:12:76:94:BE:24:92:30
a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=0;stereo=0;useinbandfec=1
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-pwd:J0mSR80MUmjeluzUrNPgT+pJ
a=ice-ufrag:SLAB
a=mid:0
a=msid:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq 51d336ff-2946-46fa-b93d-3f1acfd5d8db
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=setup:active
a=ssrc:90642905 cname:ZnNDIO/IdV65CIS9
a=ssrc:90642905 msid:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq 51d336ff-2946-46fa-b93d-3f1acfd5d8db
a=ssrc:90642905 mslabel:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq
a=ssrc:90642905 label:51d336ff-2946-46fa-b93d-3f1acfd5d8db
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendonly
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=fingerprint:sha-256 BA:56:72:51:3B:38:D9:16:D6:3C:F6:22:E3:DB:33:FF:AA:57:57:D1:D2:0D:AA:0F:91:12:76:94:BE:24:92:30
a=fmtp:124 apt=120
a=fmtp:125 apt=121
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-pwd:J0mSR80MUmjeluzUrNPgT+pJ
a=ice-ufrag:SLAB
a=mid:1
a=msid:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq 8a4b8dad-9b02-4d75-b3f0-d09c1c2d6299
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=setup:active
a=ssrc:4053784936 cname:ZnNDIO/IdV65CIS9
a=ssrc:4053784936 msid:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq 8a4b8dad-9b02-4d75-b3f0-d09c1c2d6299
a=ssrc:4053784936 mslabel:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq
a=ssrc:4053784936 label:8a4b8dad-9b02-4d75-b3f0-d09c1c2d6299
a=ssrc:179928451 cname:ZnNDIO/IdV65CIS9
a=ssrc:179928451 msid:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq 8a4b8dad-9b02-4d75-b3f0-d09c1c2d6299
a=ssrc:179928451 mslabel:pkZ2OrEINwssCBnjjTkhnQIG8tAiSXJJXsyq
a=ssrc:179928451 label:8a4b8dad-9b02-4d75-b3f0-d09c1c2d6299
a=ssrc-group:FID 4053784936 179928451
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:30
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 BA:56:72:51:3B:38:D9:16:D6:3C:F6:22:E3:DB:33:FF:AA:57:57:D1:D2:0D:AA:0F:91:12:76:94:BE:24:92:30
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-pwd:J0mSR80MUmjeluzUrNPgT+pJ
a=ice-ufrag:SLAB
a=mid:2
a=setup:active
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144

Connection log:
(generic/EMERG) Exit UDP socket connected

(ice/INFO) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.1.74:1034/UDP|stun.l.google.com:19302)): Received response; processing

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.1.74:1036/UDP|stun.l.google.com:19302)): Received response; processing

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|stun.l.google.com:19302)): Received response; processing

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.1.74:1037/UDP|stun.l.google.com:19302)): Received response; processing

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.1.74:1038/UDP|stun.l.google.com:19302)): Received response; processing

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): All candidates initialized

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) has no stream matching stream PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) has no stream matching stream PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_1 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) has no stream matching stream PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_2 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) no streams with non-empty check lists

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) no streams with pre-answer requests

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) no checks to start

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Starting check timer for stream.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default): no FROZEN/WAITING pairs for PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) is now checking

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(/1yu): setting pair to state FROZEN: /1yu|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:10.132.138.120:33895/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/CAND-PAIR(/1yu): Pairing candidate IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP (7e7f00ff):IP4:10.132.138.120:33895/UDP (7e7e1eff) priority=9114756780654461439 (7e7e1efffcfe01ff)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Starting check timer for stream.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(/1yu): setting pair to state WAITING: /1yu|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:10.132.138.120:33895/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(/1yu): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: /1yu|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:10.132.138.120:33895/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default): no FROZEN/WAITING pairs for PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Starting check timer for stream.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default): no FROZEN/WAITING pairs for PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Starting check timer for stream.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default): no FROZEN/WAITING pairs for PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(d/YG): setting pair to state FROZEN: d/YG|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:95.153.132.86:46915/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/CAND-PAIR(d/YG): Pairing candidate IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP (7e7f00ff):IP4:95.153.132.86:46915/UDP (647e1eff) priority=7241259335668335103 (647e1efffcfe01ff)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Starting check timer for stream.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(d/YG): setting pair to state WAITING: d/YG|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:95.153.132.86:46915/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(d/YG): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: d/YG|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:95.153.132.86:46915/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default): no FROZEN/WAITING pairs for PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071)): peer (PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(/1yu|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:10.132.138.120:33895/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)): Timed out

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(/1yu): setting pair to state FAILED: /1yu|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:10.132.138.120:33895/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(d/YG|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:95.153.132.86:46915/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)): Timed out

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/CAND-PAIR(d/YG): setting pair to state FAILED: d/YG|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:95.153.132.86:46915/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): state dump

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Local component 1 - dumping candidates

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(fuqo): host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(6wz3): srflx(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|stun.l.google.com:19302)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(zALX): host(IP4:192.168.1.74:50863/TCP) active

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Local component 2 - dumping candidates

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(hPCo): host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1036/UDP)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(mDXf): srflx(IP4:192.168.1.74:1036/UDP|stun.l.google.com:19302)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(0uWc): host(IP4:192.168.1.74:52391/TCP) active

(ice/ERR) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default)/STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): state dump

(ice/ERR) CAND-PAIR(/1yu): pair /1yu|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:10.132.138.120:33895/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900): state=FAILED, priority=0x7e7e1efffcfe01ff

(ice/ERR) CAND-PAIR(d/YG): pair d/YG|IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP|IP4:95.153.132.86:46915/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.1.74:1035/UDP)|candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900): state=FAILED, priority=0x647e1efffcfe01ff

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Remote component 1 in state 3 - dumping candidates

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(3mOW): candidate:668138274 1 udp 2122262783 2a00:1fa1:2ef:9e60:71c8:4b3f:1b27:2e38 40013 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 2 network-cost 900

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(vi4T): candidate:3554329308 1 udp 2122194687 10.132.138.120 33895 typ host generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(+7Ih): candidate:1766918098 1 tcp 1518283007 2a00:1fa1:2ef:9e60:71c8:4b3f:1b27:2e38 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 2 network-cost 900

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(ucK0): candidate:2639871532 1 tcp 1518214911 10.132.138.120 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309)/CAND(6Q+H): candidate:525860175 1 udp 1685987071 95.153.132.86 46915 typ srflx raddr 10.132.138.120 rport 33895 generation 0 ufrag SLAB network-id 1 network-cost 900

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071))/ICE-STREAM(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071) transport-id=transport_0 - 44add4f4:186e2461d52be5e813ef58e15f5c9309): Remote component 2 in state 0 - dumping candidates

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1603267899855000 (id=6442450950 url=https://nekita.glitch.me/room/453071):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

+++++++ END ++++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you can not directly connect two clients if any of them is behind symmetric NAT. In this case you need to have TURN server.